# Unable to launch eclipse after updating java version to java 8.........Resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, environment-variables

I updated my java version to java 8 as one of the website demands it to run its content. But after updating the java version to Java 8 it gave me trouble in launching the eclipse. I got the following prompt when i try to launch eclipse:

```
Java was started but returned exit code=13
C\:ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256
-jar
D:\CMSI\eclipse-juno\eclipse-juno2\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0
.v20120522-1813.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
D:\CMSI\eclipse-juno\eclipse-juno2\\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win3
2.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807\eclipse_1503.dll
-startup
D:\CMSI\eclipse-juno\eclipse-juno2\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0
.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 18b0_5c
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-vm C:\PragramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256
-jar
D:\CMSI\eclipse-juno\eclipse-juno2\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0
.v20120522-1813.jar
```

After complete installation the system asked me to remove the older version of java, i did not remove that thinking that my application is running in older version may be it could cause any problem with that.

I got the solution of the above problem so thought of sharing it, as this problem came across with many of my colleagues.

When the java version is updated to java8, it made an entry:

> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath

in the PATH variable(on windows system) in the System variable. So removing this entry from PATH variable would resolve the problem.

So proceed as follows:

- Right click on the My Computer icon --> Properties -->Advanced system settings --> Environment Variables
- Now under System variable scroll to the Path variable
- Select Path variable and click on edit button
- Remove the entry "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath" from it and exit

It would resolve the prblem..........Cheers!!!

Comment: Thanks for posting this, but what you should instead is answer your own question.

Comment: I got stuck in it and found the answer as well so thought of posting it with the resolution........... it can be helpful to others

Comment: Yes, it is helpful, but please post it as an answer and not as part of the question.